# Better way to create "child/nested" routes in Angular?

Tags: angular, routes

My issue seems trivial, but I don't really know where to find an answer online..

Let's take a component which displays a list of 3 fruits. Each fruit has a dedicated component.
The list URL is localhost:4200/fruit-list.
I want to be able to navigate to localhost:4200/fruit-list/banana and have banana component displayed, but only this component, not in place of the "router-outlet" in the list component like a child route would.

A simple solution would be to individually declare 'fruit-list', 'fruit-list/banana', 'fruit-list/apple'... routes, but I don't find that really elegant. Isn't there a way to simply make the fruit routes be children of the list route, but simply display the fruit component when trying to go to the child route, but not display it INSIDE of the list component.

Answer (score 2):

That is possible with a componentless route. Like this:

```
export const routes = [
  { path: 'fruit-list', children: [
    { path: '', component: ListComponent },
    { path: 'banana', component: BananaComponent },
    { path: 'apple', component: AppleComponent }
  ]}
];
```

[stack](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-afshmq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Comment: What I'd like, if possible, is some sort of syntax, similar to children routes (where you simply add the children array to the object defining your parent route and then add the objects relative to the child routes), but not having my nested components displayed in the parent but just by themselves.                   Maybe your solution is the right one, I just don't understand how to use it

Comment: What don't you understand about it? I have updated my answer though with a solution that's more to what you want

Comment: I'm very new to Angular so I didn't know how to use your solution. I solved my "issue" with route parameters, which also allows me to avoid using a variable in a service which changed with the route, and your solution pointed me to route parameters, so thank you!